# PHP: Posting a tweet on submitting a form

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, twitter

I've a template which contains a form for the user to fill. After the user successfully logs in using his/her Twitter account, the user is redirected to the template containing the form. Now, I'm trying to implement a feature wherein a tweet is posted on the user's Twitter timeline after the user submits the form.

I'm using Abraham's `twitteroauth` to implement Twitter OAuth, and also to post tweets on behalf of the user.

I'm also using the `save_post` hook to trigger a function which will post the tweet on user's Twitter account as soon as the form is submitted.

Code:

```
<pre>
<?php
/*
 *Template Name: Callback 
*/

?>  
<?php

    session_start();
    require "twitteroauth/autoload.php";
    use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

    define('CONSUMER_KEY', "XXXXXXXXXXX");
    define('CONSUMER_SECRET', "XXXXXXXXXXX");
    define('OAUTH_CALLBACK', "http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/callback/");

    $request_token = [];
    $request_token['oauth_token'] = $_SESSION['oauth_token'];
    $request_token['oauth_token_secret'] = $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'];

    if (isset($_REQUEST['oauth_token']) && $request_token['oauth_token'] !== $_REQUEST['oauth_token'])
    {
        echo "Opps! Something went wrong!";
    }

    else
    {
        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $request_token['oauth_token'], $request_token['oauth_token_secret']);
        $access_token = $connection->oauth("oauth/access_token", array("oauth_verifier" => $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']));

        //print_r($access_token);

        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $access_token;

        $access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];

        //print_r($_REQUEST['oauth_verifier']);

        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);


        $handle = $access_token['screen_name'];
        $o_token = $access_token['oauth_token'];
        $o_token_secret = $access_token['oauth_token_secret'];
        $user_id = $access_token['user_id'];
        $o_verifier = $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'];

        function cron_tweet()
        {
            $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $o_token, $o_token_secret);
            $response = $connection->post("statuses/update", array('status' => 'Versionuyyu 1.0'));
        }

        add_action('save_post', cron_tweet);

    }


?>


<script>

    var count = 0

    function addNewMessage(count)
        {       
                if(count > 5)
                {
                    window.alert("NO MORE THAN 5!");
                }
                else
                {
                    var celeb = document.createElement("input");
                    celeb.type = "text";
                    celeb.name = "tweet" + count;
                    celeb.placeholder = "Tweet" + " " + count;
                    celebrity.appendChild(celeb);

                    var date = document.createElement("input");
                    date.type = "datetime-local";
                    date.name = "date" + count;
                    date.placeholder = "message-date" + " " + count;
                    celebrity.appendChild(date);

                    celebrity.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
                    celebrity.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
                }
        }        

    function postResults()
    {
        <?php
           $post_information = array(
        'post_title' => 'New Tweet Schedule',
        'post_content' => 'Mandatory content',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'schedule_tweet',
        );

        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_information );

        add_post_meta($post_id, 'twitter_handle', $handle, true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'oauth_token', $o_token, true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'oauth_token_secret', $o_token_secret, true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'user_id', $user_id, true);

        add_post_meta($post_id, 'tweet_1', $_POST['tweet1'], true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'tweet_2', $_POST['tweet2'], true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'tweet_3', $_POST['tweet3'], true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'tweet_4', $_POST['tweet4'], true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'tweet_5', $_POST['tweet5'], true);

        add_post_meta($post_id, 'date_1', $_POST['date1'], true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'date_2', $_POST['date2'], true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'date_3', $_POST['date3'], true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'date_4', $_POST['date4'], true);
        add_post_meta($post_id, 'date_5', $_POST['date5'], true);


        ?>
    }

</script>

<form method = "POST">

    <fieldset>
        <a style = "color:red" onclick = "addNewMessage(++count)">Schedule a tweet</a>
        <div id = "celebrity"/>
    </fieldset>

    <br>
    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'post_nonce', 'post_nonce_field' ); ?>
        <button type="submit" onclick = "postResults()"><?php _e('Add Campaign', 'framework') ?></button>
    </fieldset>


</form>
```

As seen above, I've defined the following hook to trigger the function `cron_tweet` as soon as the `Submit` button is clicked by the user:

```
function cron_tweet()
        {
            $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $o_token, $o_token_secret);
            $response = $connection->post("statuses/update", array('status' => 'Versionuyyu 1.0'));
        }

        add_action('save_post', cron_tweet);
```

The `cron_tweet` function basically attempts to post the tweet on user's Twitter account.

However, the above code doesn't seem to work as intended. After the user submits the form, no tweet is being posted on the user's Twitter account.

What seems to be wrong with my code? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you seeing any errors? The most likely problem I can see are that `$o_token` and `$o_token_secret` can not be seen from in the scope of `cron_tweet`.

One solution would be to save those details into a session variable:

```
        $handle = $access_token['screen_name'];
        $_SESSION['o_token'] = $access_token['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['o_token_secret'] = $access_token['oauth_token_secret'];
        $user_id = $access_token['user_id'];
        $o_verifier = $_REQUEST['oauth_verifier'];

        function cron_tweet()
        {
            $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $_SESSION['o_token'], $_SESSION['o_token_secret']);
            $response = $connection->post("statuses/update", array('status' => 'Versionuyyu 1.0'));
        }
```

Comment: This worked. I spent hours trying to figure out what was going wrong. Thanks!